# If everything is supposed to be an object in Java (barring primative types), isn't this contradicting the point of static?

Tags: java, object-oriented, static

I often write code which makes an object and then use static methods in static classes to manipulate said object.

Am I missing the point of OOP? How do I know whether I'm thinking in the OOP mind set? I doubt I am...

Comment: The style you describe is probably more of a *functional* style than an object-oriented one.  It's a perfectly valid technique, especially if you are returning new objects from your methods.

Comment: see also: [Significant amount of the time, I can't think of a reason to have an object instead of a static class. Do objects have more benefits than I think?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/242940/significant-amount-of-the-time-i-cant-think-of-a-reason-to-have-an-object-inst)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you are missing OOP principles in your coding.** OOP is not about bearing primitive types, OOP is about having an object that has responsibilities(methods essentially).

[GRASP Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)) are a good start to learn where which method belongs in OOP.

In OOP you want to treat most instances as objects that have responsibilities and instance fields(instance specific variables). However, sometimes(and I mean sometimes) you would find a need to have a static class, which is perfectly valid as long as you really sure this class has no need for an instance. But before you settle down with creating one, think - "Am I missing an object?".

**Your Functional Way:**

```
var alice = new Person("Alice");

ChangeName(alice, "John");

// Somewhere in your static code
function ChangeName(Person person, string name) {
    person.name = name;
}
```

**OOP Way:**

```
var alice = new Person("Alice");
alice.ChangeName("John");

public class Person {
    private _name;    

    public Person(string name) {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void ChangeName(string name) {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but in what universe could the first code you wrote be considered "functional" in any way at all?